# How to pass data from a Spinner to other activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm working on an application that consists on a shopping cart, where the user selects which pizza and which drink he wants, using a spinner for each selection.
I have been working for a week on how to send the data selected in the spinner to the next activity and display it on a textview, but I don't know how to do it.

My both spinners are working correctly.

Code for the spinner

```
    Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = 
    ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
    R.array.numbers, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);      
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource  
    (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    Spinner spinner2 = findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = 
    ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
    R.array.drinks, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter1);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);



    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
    position, long l) {
    String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
```

Code for the intent

```
    Button enviar = findViewById(R.id.enviar);
    enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent resumenPedido = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Resumen.class);
            startActivityForResult(resumenPedido, 1);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use Intent.putExtra() method. Please check the following and use accordingly.

This is how you can get the selected values from spinner:

```
CharSequence spinner1SelectedData  = (CharSequence) spinner.getSelectedItem();
CharSequence spinner2SelectedData  = (CharSequence) spinner2.getSelectedItem();
```

And then onClick listener replace it with the following:

```
Intent resumenPedido = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Resumen.class);
resumePedido.putExtra("data_spinner_1", spinner1SelectedData.toString());  
resumePedido.putExtra("data_spinner_2", spinner2SelectedData.toString());
startActivity(mIntent);
```

You don't have to use startActivityForResult unless you want callback to source activity.

In the 2nd activity you can get the data as follows:

```
  if (getIntent() != null){
      String spinner1Value = getIntent().getStringExtra("data_spinner_1");
      String spinner2Value = getIntent().getStringExtra("data_spinner_2");
  }
```

Comment: It just didn't work, I checked the documentation and then it worked

Comment: Okay, so that means you've got the solution for your problem, right?

Comment: Please update your code with the solution then, somebody else might get help from it

Answer (score 1):

First of all

> you need to differentiate spinner 1 `onItemSelectedListner` with
>   spinner 2

Second thing

> for storing user selected value from spinner take two variables

string_spinner1 and string_spinner2 and 
store it inside `onItemSelectedListner`

```
string_spinner1 = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()  //FOR SPINNER 1 LISTENER
string_spinner2 = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() //FOR SPINNER 2 LISTENER
```

Third Thing pass that value in your intent like this>

```
Intent resumenPedido = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Resumen.class);
resumenPedido.putExtra('spinner1_data',string_spinner1);
resumenPedido.putExtra('spinner2_data',string_spinner2);
startActivity(resumenPedido);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `EXTRA` for intent
your `onClick` should look like this

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent resumenPedido = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Resumen.class);
        resumePedido.putExtra(FLAG, data);  
        startActivityForResult(resumenPedido, 1);
    }
```

and in new activity use method

```
data = getIntent().getExtras(FLAG);
```

check [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Comment: data = getIntent().getExtra(FLAG);
this part seems incomplete.There is no any method getIntent().getExtra() method.

Comment: @vikasjha https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent

Comment: Yes i had went through the document. There is no such method.

Comment: oh. very sorry))) data = getIntent().getExtras(FLAG);

Comment: Still it is not correct.It should be data = getIntent().getExtras().get(FLAG);
But its ok. Please do not take it otherwise.Happy Coding